# How to calculate statistical properties before and after specific cutoff point in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame({'idx':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5], 'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'value':[5,10,15,20,25, 55,65,75,85,97]})
```

I have another that looks like this:

```
dt_idx = pd.DataFrame({'cutoff':[1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4]})
```

For the 3 "most common" `cutoff`s from the `dt_idx` (in this toy example it is 3,5 and 2), I would like to obtain the `mean` and the `std` of the `value` column of the `dt` dataframe, for the following 2 groups:

- `idx <= cutoff` and
- `idx > cutoff`

Is there a pythonic way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop here is a good option. Get the cutoffs you care about using `value_counts` and then loop over those cutoffs. You can use `groupby` to get both the `<=` and `>` at the same time. Store everything in a dict, keyed by the cutoffs, and then you can `concat` to get a DataFrame with a MultiIndex.

```
d = {}
for cutoff in dt_idx.cutoff.value_counts().head(3).index:
    d[cutoff] = dt.groupby(dt.idx.gt(cutoff))['value'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
    
pd.concat(d, names=['cutoff', 'greater_than_cutoff'])
```

---

```
                                 mean        std
cutoff greater_than_cutoff                      
2      False                33.750000  30.652624
       True                 52.833333  36.771819
3      False                37.500000  30.943497
       True                 56.750000  39.903007
5      False                45.200000  34.080949
```

---

If you want to use those cutoffs as ranges then we'll create the list, adding `np.inf` to the end, and we can use a single `groupby` with `pd.cut` to make the groups.

```
bins = dt_idx.cutoff.value_counts().head(3).index.sort_values().tolist() + [np.inf]
#[2, 3, 5, inf]

dt.groupby(pd.cut(dt.idx, bins, right=False))['value'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
#             mean        std
#idx                         
#[2.0, 3.0)  37.50  38.890873
#[3.0, 5.0)  48.75  36.371921
#[5.0, inf)  61.00  50.911688
```

Comment: can the multiindex be dropped and have a regular index ?

Comment: then information is lost .. keep in mind that you have 3 degrees of freedom (mean or variance, lower or higher, and level (2, 3 or 5)) 
that's why you need MultiIndex, another option is to use a DataFrames dictionary @quant

Comment: @ALollz probably this should be a separate question, but is it possible to get the `mean` and the `std` for "within the groups of the cutoffs" ? so in this case it would be the groups [2,3), [3,5), [5,inf)

Comment: @quant eh it's close enough. Similar method to get the values, we just sort so the bins are always monotonic, and then you can use `pd.cut` to group (It gives nice Inverval labels)

Answer (score 2):

First we get the 3 most common values, then we use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for each of these values.

```
import numpy as np
n=3
l = dt_idx['cutoff'].value_counts()[:n].index

new_df = pd.concat({val : dt.groupby(np.where(dt['idx'].le(val),
                                              'less than or equal',
                                              'higher'))['value']
                            .agg(['mean','std'])
                    for val in l}, axis=1)
print(new_df)

                            2                 3                5           
                         mean        std   mean        std  mean        std
higher              52.833333  36.771819  56.75  39.903007   NaN        NaN
less than or equal  33.750000  30.652624  37.50  30.943497  45.2  34.080949

#new_df.stack(0).swaplevel().sort_index()
#                           mean        std
#2 higher              52.833333  36.771819
#  less than or equal  33.750000  30.652624
#3 higher              56.750000  39.903007
#  less than or equal  37.500000  30.943497
#5 less than or equal  45.200000  34.080949
```